# Eclipse Juno org.eclipse.ui.ide.ResourceUtil

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-juno

I'm porting a plugin to Eclipse 4.2 (Juno), but I'm having trouble finding an alternative to **org.eclipse.ui.ide.ResourceUtil**. It was removed from org.eclipse.ui.ide.

The respective method I need is **static IEditorPart findEditor(IWorkbenchPage page, IFile file)**.

Is there any alternative to findEditor for Juno?

Should I just write a function to search the WorkBench editorReferences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The class is still there.  It's part of the API.

http://www.eclipse.org/forums/index.php/mv/msg/487235/1057997/#msg_1057997

Comment: Thanks for the answer that actually worked. Change the jars from version 4.2 to 3.8.